# Variable wont update in second client window

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

im very new to node, and i am trying to make a multiplayer tic-tac-toe game i can play on my local webserver.

So far, everything works fine, if i play from one browser, and if i open a second browser, it updates itself fine when i click in the first one. The issue is, that when i do a move in one window, and i emit the variable "turn", when i then click in the second window for the next move, it acts like its the first move, (and just places another X)

I am confused as to why this happens, since i send the turn variable to the backend, make sure its correct, then send it back to the frontend.

server.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {cors: {origin: "*"}});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("/home/pi/nodeTacTow/index.html");
})

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server started at port 3000...")
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log("Welcome MR" + socket.id);
  socket.join("GameRoom");

  socket.on('move', (moveOne, turn) => {

    console.log(turn);
    socket.broadcast.emit('move', moveOne, turn);

  });

  socket.on('win', (player) => {
    console.log("WINNER IS: " + player)
  })

})
```

main.js

```js
var gridOne = document.getElementById('grid-item-one');
var gridTwo = document.getElementById('grid-item-two');
var gridThree = document.getElementById('grid-item-three');
var gridFour = document.getElementById('grid-item-four');
var gridFive = document.getElementById('grid-item-five');
var gridSix = document.getElementById('grid-item-six');
var gridSeven = document.getElementById('grid-item-seven');
var gridEight = document.getElementById('grid-item-eight');
var gridNine = document.getElementById('grid-item-nine');

var gridArray = [gridOne, gridTwo, gridThree, gridFour, gridFive, gridSix, gridSeven, gridEight, gridNine];

const socket = io('http://192.168.10.130:3000/')

var cell = [];

var playerOnePick = [];
var playerTwoPick = [];

var textField = document.getElementById('text-field');

var turn = 0;

var placed = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];

function placeBet(place, numb){
  var player;
  var name;
    
  if(turn === 0 && place.innerHTML === ""){
        
    playerOnePick.push(numb);

    place.innerHTML = '<h1 class="gameX">X</h1>';
    turn = 1;
    textField.innerHTML= "Player 2's turn";
    player = playerOnePick;
    name = "PLAYER ONE";
    
  } else if(turn === 1 && place.innerHTML === ""){
    playerTwoPick.push(numb);
    place.innerHTML = '<h1 class="gameO">O</h1>';
    turn = 0;
    textField.innerHTML= "Player 1' turn";
    player = playerTwoPick;
    name = "PLAYER TWO"  
        
  }

  socket.emit('move', numb, turn);
    
  placed[numb - 1] = numb;
  console.log("Player one picked: " + playerOnePick + " Player two picked: " + playerTwoPick);
    
  checkWin(player, name);
 
}

var a;
var b;
var c;
function checkWin(player, name){

  var valueOne = '<h1 class="gameO">O</h1>';
  var valueTwo = '<h1 class="gameX">X</h1>';

  var winCombos = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [3, 6, 9],
    [1, 5, 9],
    [3, 5, 7]
  ];

  // if(playerOnePick.includes(1 && 2 && 3)){
  //     console.log(" YEAH DUDE U WON")
  // }

  // circle through winCombo array, and see if playerpickarray includes the winCombos

  for(var i = 0; i < winCombos.length; i++){

    const winCondition = winCombos[i];
    a = winCondition[0];
    b = winCondition[1];
    c = winCondition[2];

    // If wincondition array are filled with player cell array picks, u win
        
    if (a === '' || b === '' || c === '') {
      continue;
    }
    if (player.includes(a) && player.includes(b) && player.includes(c)) {
      textField.innerHTML = name + " IS THE WINNER";
      socket.emit("win", name);
      break;
    }
  }  
}

function startGame(){

  playerOnePick=[];
  playerTwoPick=[];
  textField.innerHTML="Player 1's turn";
  turn = 0;

  // clear the gameBoard

  for(var i = 0; i < gridArray.length; i++){
    gridArray[i].innerHTML = "";
  }
}

socket.on("connection", () => {
  console.log("Welcome")
});

socket.on('move', (number, turn) => {

  if(turn === 1){
    gridArray[number-1].innerHTML='<h1 class="gameX">X</h1>';
    textField.innerHTML="Player 2's turn";
    turn = 0;
        
  } else if(turn === 0){
    gridArray[number-1].innerHTML='<h1 class="gameO">O</h1>';
    textField.innerHTML="Player 1's turn";
    turn = 1;
  }
    
})

socket.on('win', (name) => {
  textField.innerHTML= name + "IS THE WINNER!";
})
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 id="text-field">Player 1's turn</h2>

    <div class="grid-container">

      <div id="grid-item-one" class="grid-item" onclick="placeBet(gridOne, 1)"></div>
      <div id="grid-item-two" class="grid-item" onclick="placeBet(gridTwo, 2)"></div>
      <div id="grid-item-three" class="grid-item" onclick="placeBet(gridThree, 3)"></div>
      <div id="grid-item-four" class="grid-item" onclick="placeBet(gridFour, 4)"></div>
      <div id="grid-item-five" class="grid-item" onclick="placeBet(gridFive, 5)"></div>
      <div id="grid-item-six" class="grid-item" onclick="placeBet(gridSix, 6)"></div>
      <div id="grid-item-seven" class="grid-item" onclick="placeBet(gridSeven, 7)"></div>
      <div id="grid-item-eight" class="grid-item" onclick="placeBet(gridEight, 8)"></div>
      <div id="grid-item-nine" class="grid-item" onclick="placeBet(gridNine, 9)"></div>
    
    </div>

    <button id="start-but" onclick="startGame()">Start game</button>
    
    <script src="/main.js">

    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

index.css

```css
body {
  background-color: #41B3A3;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 120px 120px 120px; 
  grid-template-rows: 120px 120px 120px 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-item{
  background-color: #E8A87C;
  border: 1px solid #C38D9E;
}
.gameX{
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 100px;
  left: 20px;
  color: #E27D60;
  
}
.gameO{
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 100px;
  left: 20px;
  color: #85DCBD;
}

#start-but{
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have a **global** variable `turn`. In your `socket.on("move")` listener in the frontend, you also have a **local** `turn` variable. Thus, when you try to change the `turn` variable, you are actually only changing the **local** variable, and not the **global** one.

To fix this, you can simply rename the parameter in the `socket.on("move")`:

```js
socket.on("move", (number, actionTurn) => {
  // Now, 'turn' references the global variable, and 'actionTurn' represents the turn number emitted from the server.
  if(actionTurn === 1){
    gridArray[number-1].innerHTML = '<h1 class="gameX">X</h1>';
    textField.innerHTML = "Player 2's turn";
    turn = 0;
  } else if(actionTurn === 0){
    gridArray[number-1].innerHTML = '<h1 class="gameO">O</h1>';
    textField.innerHTML = "Player 1's turn";
    turn = 1;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much you kind soul! You have saved me several more days of frustration!